# Rspec, how to expect to receive with only a subset of key value pair?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have a spec that expects a class to receive a method with some arguments. I only want to check for a subset of key/value pair from the argument hash :

```
  it 'calls Stripe::Checkout::Session#create with the correct line items' do
      expect(Stripe::Checkout::Session).to receive(:create).with({
          line_items: [{
            price: "bla",
            quantity: 1
          }],
        }
      )
      subject
    end
```

here I only want to check that line_items is present in the argument hash with the correct value.

However the actual hash received has more values and I get the following error :

```
#<Stripe::Checkout::Session (class)> received :create with unexpected arguments
     expected: ({:line_items=>[{:price=>"bla", :quantity=>1}]}, *(any args))
          got: ({:allow_promotion_codes=>true, :automatic_tax=>{:enabled=>true}, :billing_address_collection=>"requir...vh.me/fr/thank-you?checkout_session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}", :tax_id_collection=>{:enabled=>true}}, {:stripe_account=>"bla"})
```

How can I tell rspec to only check for the presence of a subset of key/value pair ?

Answer (score 3):

You want `hash_including`, which matches subsets of hashes:

```
  ...to receive(:create).with(hash_including(
    line_items: [{
      price: "bla",
      quantity: 1
    }],
  )
```

See the docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments

Comment: I have seen this, I am stil getting the same error with hash_including :  #<Stripe::Checkout::Session (class)> received :create with unexpected arguments
         expected: (hash_including(:allow_promotion_codes=>true))
              got: ({:allow_promotion_codes=>true, :automatic_tax=>{:enabled=>true}, :billing_address_collection=>"requir...vh.me/fr/thank-you?checkout_session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}", :tax_id_collection=>{:enabled=>true}}, {:stripe_account=>"bla"})